# WPF Webview's IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled ignored when using ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, itemtemplate

**This simple way of doing is working fine**

If I use a [WebView](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/), put `IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled` to `true`, and load a local network website, it will load properly.

```
<WPF:WebView Source="http://localnetworkwebsite"  
            NavigationStarting="Wvc_NavigationStarting" 
            NavigationCompleted="Wvc_NavigationCompleted" 
            IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled="True" />
```

**This way of doing is NOT working**

In my application, I want to manage several webpage simultaneously (like tabs on a standalone browser), so I use an `ItemControl` to instantiate the WebView's count I need (this number is not always the same).

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsWebview" ItemsSource="{Binding WebviewsDataSource}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid></Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <!--Item-->
            <WPF:WebView Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" Source="{Binding Source}"  
                            NavigationStarting="Wvc_NavigationStarting" 
                            NavigationCompleted="Wvc_NavigationCompleted" 
                            IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled="True" />
            <!--End Item-->

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And then, I change the `Source` of ths WebView, and hide/make them visible using the ViewModel:

```
public class WebviewViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Guid LinkedId { get; set; }

    private System.Windows.Visibility _visibility;
    public Visibility Visibility
    {
        get
        {
            return _visibility;
        }

        set
        {
            _visibility = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Visibility)));
        }
    }

    private Uri _source;
    public Uri Source
    {
        get
        {
            return _source;
        }

        set
        {
            _source = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Source)));
        }
    }
}
```

`WebviewsDataSource` is `ObservableCollection<WebviewViewModel>`

The whole thing seems to works, but ONLY for the external websites, not for the local one. I always get an `404 NotFound` for the local network sites when using this ways for creating WebViews, as if `IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled` was ignored. But the local site works with the simple method.

I've checked the states of the WebViews after the creation, and the `IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled` value is still to `true`.

**So...**

Since this control is [relatively new](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/), this looks like a bug to me...
But am i doing something wrong?

**Edit**

Minimal `.sln` of the problem can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/files/2261631/WebViewBugReport.zip).

This simple WPF application will fail to open local network website in `ItemTemplate` (while external site will works), and will succeed to open local network websites when using the control directly.

Just change the `WebviewsDataSource` value in `MainWindowViewModel.cs` to test local network urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft team confirmed this as a bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2356

*Edit*: The bug has been fixed and merged in the v4.0.0. If you experience this problem, you just need to update the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls` nuget package to 4.0.1+